# Is it possible to keep form both disabled and clickable simultaneously in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with angularjs and using fieldset I want to make form disabled and also clickable at the same time, any work-around available for this?

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. clickable and disabled are two opposites things. making an input "disabled" prevent the user to write anything an it. You can active "disabled" dynamicly with ng-disabled="boolValue"

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you is to use `ng-readonly`

```
<input type="text" ng-readonly="isFieldReadonly">
```

Then trigger it in your controller:

```
$scope.isFieldReadonly = true;
```

Comment: I guess ng-readonly does not work with drop-downs that's the problem I am facing with readonly

Comment: You should really give us the full picture when posting a question, including code. We can't guess what you are trying to do. Post some code